# Finding the average force required to stretch a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, spring

I have a homework assignment that is making me find the average force required to stretch a spring. This is the question:

Given a spring constant of 20, find the average force required to stretch the spring from 3 m to 4 m.

I know that Hooke's Law is F = -kx but the "average" part is confusing me. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The force required to stretch the spring by $3$ m is $60$ N. The force required to stretch the spring by $4$ m is $80$ N. One interpretation of the question is to simply take the average of these two values - this gives you the average force with respect to distance stretched.

However, the question is ambiguous since it does not tell you what variable you are averaging over. There is also, for example, have an average force with respect to time (although in this case I don't think you are given enough information to calculate the average force with respect to time).

Comment: Another way to think about it if you define "average force" to be such that (work done) = (average force)*(displacement), similar to how you define an average velocity for an object with variable instantaneous velocity.  This gives you the same result as the method you describe above but — at least to my mind — seems a little less *ad hoc*.